# WordPress -- Is it possible to schedule monthly updates on applicable plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I know there are a number of plugins that allow selective automated plugin updates in WordPress, and functions.php can be edited to force automatic plugin updates, however I want to know if it is possible to run an automated batch update on applicable (update available) plugins on a monthly basis?

Many thanks as always!

Comment: Yes there is. Do a search for `wp_cron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @disinfor's comment it looks like wp_cron / wp_schedule_event is the best approach.

Hopefully these references will be of use -

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event